# asp.net Crystal Reports, Database Logon Failed

Tags: asp.net, .net, crystal-reports

I can't get this report exported as a pdf. I've done this many times before, but now I hit a brick wall. any help would be appreciated.

This is on a windows 7 64 bit machine.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

```
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Database logon failed.

Source Error: 



Line 25:         exportOpts.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat
Line 26:         exportOpts.ExportFormatOptions = pdfOpts
Line 27:         report.ExportToHttpResponse(exportOpts, Response, False, "")
Line 28: 
Line 29:     End Sub

Stack Trace: 



[COMException (0x8004100f): Database logon failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext) +0
   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +519

[LogOnException: Database logon failed.]
   CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e) +1243
   CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +621
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext) +1201
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToStream(ExportOptions options) +150
   CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToHttpResponse(ExportOptions options, HttpResponse response, Boolean asAttachment, String attachmentName) +212
   reports_CreateReport.generateReport(DataSet ds, String reportpath, ArrayList params) in C:\Users\boruch\Dropbox\Korns-ConnectionStr\reports\CreateReport.aspx.vb:27
   reports_CreateReport.btn_GenReport_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Users\boruch\Dropbox\Korns-ConnectionStr\reports\CreateReport.aspx.vb:58
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9552602
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724




--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18044
```

Comment: Which model have been used to create crystal report? PULL or PUSH?

Comment: Im using push; with dataset while designing the report, and I'm filling the dataset in codebehind and setting it as the report source.

Comment: Is it only this report that fails to export to PDF or do you have others that behave likewise? A common issue is that database connectivity details aren't being changed on all data connections in the report (i.e. those against subreports).

Comment: Does the report contain any parameters which are supposed to get values from a db, like a dropdown or something?

Comment: @Zec, All reports throw the same error

Comment: @user1429080, I tired reports with and without parameters. The error stays the same.

Comment: OK, you've ruled out parameters and you've ensured you're updating the connections to all data sources in your reports as per my initial comment. Could it be as simple as having the wrong DB login details? Can you tell us which database software you're using and your chosen method of connecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to go ahead and post what I have so that maybe it'll help you. We gave up on Crystal because it was just too sketchy (I believe the first time the export would fail and then it would work every time after that until the app shut down) and SAP basically told us they didn't care if we took a hike, so we did. We switched to SSRS and are far happier for it... But I digress.

You don't show a lot of code, so I don't know if this is how yours is working. Also, mine is C#, so you'll need to convert... But hopefully you can find the solution to your problem somewhere in this example. I imagine it's going to be in the setting of the credentials...

Load the document:

```
ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
rd.Load(rptFile);
```

Set credentials

```
ConnectionInfo connectInfo = new ConnectionInfo()
{
    ServerName = dbServer,
    DatabaseName = "",
    UserID = userId,
    Password = password
};
rd.SetDatabaseLogon(userId, password);
foreach (Table tbl in rd.Database.Tables)
{
    tbl.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = connectInfo;
    tbl.ApplyLogOnInfo(tbl.LogOnInfo);
}
```

Then setup the export:

```
DiskFileDestinationOptions CrDiskFileDestinationOptions = new DiskFileDestinationOptions();
ExportOptions CrExportOptions;
PdfRtfWordFormatOptions pdfFormatOptions = new PdfRtfWordFormatOptions();
CrDiskFileDestinationOptions.DiskFileName = outputPath;
CrExportOptions = rd.ExportOptions;
{
    CrExportOptions.ExportDestinationType = ExportDestinationType.DiskFile;
    CrExportOptions.ExportFormatType = ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat;
    CrExportOptions.DestinationOptions = CrDiskFileDestinationOptions;
    CrExportOptions.FormatOptions = pdfFormatOptions;
}
```

Supply report parameters

```
SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(rd, "IP_COMP_CODE", cc);
SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(rd, "IP_YEAR", yr);
SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(rd, "IP_WEEK", wk);
```

and export...

```
rd.Export();
```

And the implementation for SetCurrentValuesForParameterField:

```
private void SetCurrentValuesForParameterField(ReportDocument reportDocument, string paramFieldName, int value)
{
    ParameterDiscreteValue parameterDiscreteValue = new ParameterDiscreteValue();
    parameterDiscreteValue.Value = value;

    ParameterValues currentParameterValues = new ParameterValues();
    currentParameterValues.Add(parameterDiscreteValue);

    reportDocument.DataDefinition.ParameterFields[paramFieldName].ApplyCurrentValues(currentParameterValues);
}
```

Comment: Saved couple of my hours. Upvoted. Thanks @Pete. But passing parameter in your method is slightly complicated. I found a simpler one like `rd.SetParameterValue("ParameterName", parameterValue);` I know this is an old post. But still someone else might find this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I too got this error.. I had sort it out by checking in my datatable values.. I had missed out to take a query for one datatable..

For Ex:
i had 11 DataTables in my Crystal report dataset.. But i miss to take a query for data table 11..
After i checked out and Corrected it.. Now my excel and PDf is working properly without getting database log on failed error..

hope it may useful for u guyzzz...